# Trying to plot data from two different datasets with two axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am using chemistry and precipitation data in the following two df:

```
    chem_df
    rain_df
```

I plotted the two datasets using ggplot() and in order to get 2 axes used the sex.axis function of the scale_y_continuous as follows:

```
    chem_rain_fig <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = chem_df, aes(x = Date, y = Temp)) +
    geom_line(data = rain_df, aes(x = Date, y = Rain)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Temp", sec.axis = (.~*, name = "Rain"))
```

But it keeps plotting both of the data sets to the original y-axis as follows:
[Graph with Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB6Zs.png)
I would like to just note that the rain data is between 0-10 cm, so that is why it follows the first axis and not the secondary axis with the limit(0,10)

Answer (score 0):

[This might answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales#49498838)

In essence, you have to manually transform your data and scale to make it appear the right size. Can't try without sample data but this should work, multiplying by 2 and dividing the scale:

```r
    chem_rain_fig <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = chem_df, aes(x = Date, y = Temp)) +
    geom_line(data = rain_df, aes(x = Date, y = Rain*2)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Temp", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2, name = "Rain"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.